# Merging three tags for same SFMC feature

Tags: discussion

Currently three tags exist, which basically relate to the same Marketing Cloud related feature:

[einstein-recommendations](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/einstein-recommendations),
[predictive-intelligence](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predictive-intelligence) and
[personalization-builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personalization-builder)

Preferably, I see a benefit of these three being merged, unless there are any objections?

Comment: What's the canonical name for the feature, Lukas? That is, which tag should "win"?

Comment: Apologies, of course this is an essential detail, @DavidReed - Einstein Recommendations is the canonical name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've merged the tags `predictive-intelligence` and `personalization-builder` into `einstein-recommendations`. I've also created tag synonyms so that those tags will in the future map transparently to `einstein-recommendations`.

Comment: Will the tag scores be recalculated, so they will be aggregated across all the above tags, and attributed to Einstein-recommendations, going forward?

Comment: I _think_ so, but I can't swear to it.